# Como hacer que un span me lo tome como input

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, script

como puedo hacer para que un resultado de un span me lo tome como un input y se pueda guardar en mi base de datos

No me guarda las variables "prima" "iva" y "total", si me muestra el resultado en dichos campos pero al momento de querer guardar no me deja por que dice que no tienen nada

```
<script>
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/10000;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/10000;

  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = + descuento;
  resulta2.innerHTML = + iva.toFixed(2);
  resultado3.innerHTML = iva.toFixed(2) - descuento.toFixed(2);
}
    </script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Nuevo Certificado - Container All Risk</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Toastr style -->
    <link href="css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Gritter -->
    <link href="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        #div1 {margin: 5px;}

    </style>
</head>

<body class="fixed-sidebar skin-3">

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $razonSocial = $_POST["razonsocial"];
    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $cliente = $_POST["Cliente"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];
    $moneda = $_POST["moneda"];
    $mercancia = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $importe = $_POST["importe"];
    $tipoOperacion = $_POST["TipoOperacion"];
    $fechaAlta = $_POST["FechaAlta"];
    $detalles = $_POST["detalles"];
    $tipoTransporte = $_POST["TipoTransporte"];
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["FechaSalida"];
    $fechaLlegada = $_POST["FechaLlegada"];
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $porigen = $_POST["porigen"];
    $eorigen = $_POST["eorigen"];
    $corigen = $_POST["corigen"];
    $pdestino = $_POST["pdestino"];
    $edestino = $_POST["edestino"];
    $cdestino = $_POST["cdestino"];
    $poliza = $_POST["poliza"];
    $cuota = $_POST["cuota"];
    $prima = $_POST["prima"];
    $gastosexp = $_POST["gastosexp"];
    $iva = $_POST["iva"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];


    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';

    }else{
       query("
        INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc,
          moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta,
          detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada,
          folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino,
          edestino, cdestino, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total)
          VALUES ('".$idCliente."', '".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."',
          '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', '".$mercancia."', '".$importe."',
          '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', '".$detalles."',
          '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."',
          '".$folio."', '".$porigen."', '".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."',
          '".$pdestino."', '".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$poliza."',
          '".$cuota."', '".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')
    ");

}
}
?>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="result"
            type="number" name="prima" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>

        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="resultado3"
            type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="resulta2"
            type="number" name="total" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el error que me sale, todos los demas campos si me los agrega pero como esas variables ya me las da automaticamente no me las guarda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Asi es como lo tengo modificado, pero en los resultados me sale NaN en cuanto pongo el primer valor

```js
<script>
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").innerText)
  var valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor2").innerText)

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
        
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = + descuento.toFixed(2);
  resulta2.innerHTML = + iva.toFixed(2);
  resultado3.innerHTML = iva - descuento;
}
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form id="nclientes" name="nclientes" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Datos del Asegurado</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon Social</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input name="razonsocial" type="text"  autocomplete="off" required title="Completar campo" class="typeahead_2 form-control" <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo 'value="'. $_COOKIE["usuario"] . '" disabled';
}
?> />
                                        <input id="idCliente" name="idCliente" type="hidden" value="<?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo $_COOKIE["idUsuario"];
}
?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Alta</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="datetime-local" name="FechaAlta" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Beneficiario Preferente</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cliente</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="Cliente" class="form-control m-b"></div> 
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">RFC</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="rfc" class="form-control m-b"></div> 
                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Detalles del Certificado</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Moneda</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="moneda" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado de la Mercancia</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="mercancia" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bienes Asegurados</label>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-8">
                                        <select name="TipoOperacion" id="tipoOperacion" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione Opcion</option>
                                            <option value="Embarque de Materia Prima">Embarque de Materia Prima</option>
                                            <option value="Abarrotes No Perecederos">Abarrotes No Perecederos</option>
                                            <option value="Aparatos Electrodomesticos">Aparatos Electrodomesticos</option>
                                            <option value="Articulos de Mercancia">Articulos de Mercancia</option>
                                            <option value="Articulos de Papeleria">Articulos de Papeleria</option>
                                            <option value="Articulos de Perfumeria">Articulos de Perfumeria</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripcion del Embarque</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"><textarea type="text" name="detalles" class="form-control m-b"></textarea></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Transito / Medio de Trasporte</h3>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-12">
                                        <select name="TipoTransporte" id="tipoOperacion" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione Opcion</option>
                                            <option value="Maritimo">Maritimo</option>
                                            <option value="Aereo">Aereo</option>
                                            <option value="Terrestre">Terrestre</option>
                                            <option value="Maritimo y Terrestre">Maritimo y Terrestre</option>
                                            <option value="Ferrocaril">Ferrocaril</option>
                                            <option value="Paqueteria">Paqueteria</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div> 
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Fecha de Salida</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="datetime-local" name="FechaSalida" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>" class="form-control"></div> 
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Fecha de Llegada</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="datetime-local" name="FechaLlegada" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>" class="form-control"></div> 
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Folio Factura</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="folio" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Origen y Destino</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="porigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="eorigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="corigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="pdestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="edestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="cdestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-3">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%"  checked>Continuacion de Viaje
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%"  checked>No Continuacion de Viaje
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%"  checked>No Continuacion de Viaje
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Informacion de emision</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Poliza</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="poliza" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="result" type="text" name="prima" value="<?php echo $prima?>" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gastos de Expedicion</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="gastosexp" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><span id="resulta2" type="text" name="total" class="form-control m-b"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Generar certificado</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Introduciendo esa información en un `form` que recibas en la superglobal $_POST como pareces hacer? A ver, vamos a hacer las cosas bien: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y añade el formulario aunque sea desde JS a ver qué podemos hacer...

Comment: Con spa**m** supongo que quieres decir `<span>`

Comment: Si, perdon es con N

Comment: deberias usar javascript para acceder a los valores de los mismos y enviarlo por ajax o a su vez crear input tipo hidden y estos tendrias los mismos valores del span

Comment: Algo asi? <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="resulta2"
            type="hidden" name="total" class="form-control m-b"></div>

Comment: si exacto @IsaiasAlejandroSanchez y tomarias los valores de los input tipo hidden

Comment: No me funciona men, cambio <span id="resulta2" type="number" name="total" class="form-control m-b"></span> por <input id="resulta2" type="hidden" name="total" class="form-control m-b"> y me desaparece el campo

Answer (score 1):

Los únicos elementos que tienen la propiedad `value` son los input, si quieres el contenido de un `span` tienes que usar `innerText` o `innerHTML`. La diferencia entre uno y otro es que `innerText` te devuelve el contenido como texto y la propiedad `innerHTML` te lo devuelve como texto y html, esto quiere decir que si dentro de este elemento habían más elementos html, puedes usarlos como lo que son, elementos html, esto implica que puedes editar el contenido del documento de esta forma

```js
const valueInput = document.getElementById('inp').value;
const contentSpan = document.getElementById('spn').innerText;

console.log(`Valor input: ${valueInput} || Contenido span: ${contentSpan}`);
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="10">
<span id="spn" >20</span>
```

Comment: Te refieres a que solo cambie 
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
por
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").innerText;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").innerText;
??????

Comment: claro, solo los input tienen "valores". El resto de los elementos tienen contenido que puede ser texto o html, es así como se saca información de tablas por ejemplo

Comment: también puedes reemplazar los span por input pero deshabilitados de edición y ya con eso podrás leer con la propiedad `value`. También puedes guardar la información en atributos o hacer lo que te sugirieron en los comentarios, tener un input escondido, hay muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres. Lo importante aquí es que el error que tienes es que estás usando la propiedad `value` en objetos que no lo tienen y eso es lo que debes saber

Comment: Cambie "var" por "const" y ".value" por "innerText; pero no me genera los resultados en automatico

Answer (score 0):

Puedes montar con jQuery unos inputs ocultos justo después de los span y enviarlo con GET o POST y los valores que buscas.

Algo así:

```
$('span').each(function(){
        var clase=$(this).attr('class');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var texto=$(this).text();
        var name=$(this).data('id-tipo');
        // $(this).remove();
        $(this).after('<input id="'+id+'" class="'+clase+'" type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="'+texto+'">');
        //$(this).remove(); si descomentas esto borra el span y pone el input en su lugar si el input lo cambias a type="text"
    });
```

**Actualizo código**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Nuevo Certificado - Container All Risk</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Toastr style -->
    <link href="css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Gritter -->
    <link href="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #div1 {margin: 5px;}

    </style>
</head>

<body class="fixed-sidebar skin-3">

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $razonSocial = $_POST["razonsocial"];
    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $cliente = $_POST["Cliente"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];
    $moneda = $_POST["moneda"];
    $mercancia = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $importe = $_POST["importe"];
    $tipoOperacion = $_POST["TipoOperacion"];
    $fechaAlta = $_POST["FechaAlta"];
    $detalles = $_POST["detalles"];
    $tipoTransporte = $_POST["TipoTransporte"];
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["FechaSalida"];
    $fechaLlegada = $_POST["FechaLlegada"];
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $porigen = $_POST["porigen"];
    $eorigen = $_POST["eorigen"];
    $corigen = $_POST["corigen"];
    $pdestino = $_POST["pdestino"];
    $edestino = $_POST["edestino"];
    $cdestino = $_POST["cdestino"];
    $poliza = $_POST["poliza"];
    $cuota = $_POST["cuota"];
    $prima = $_POST["prima"];
    $gastosexp = $_POST["gastosexp"];
    $iva = $_POST["iva"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];


    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';

    }else{
       query("
        INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc,
          moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta,
          detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada,
          folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino,
          edestino, cdestino, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total)
          VALUES ('".$idCliente."', '".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."',
          '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', '".$mercancia."', '".$importe."',
          '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', '".$detalles."',
          '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."',
          '".$folio."', '".$porigen."', '".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."',
          '".$pdestino."', '".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$poliza."',
          '".$cuota."', '".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')
    ");

}
}
?>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span id="result"
            type="number" name="prima" class="form-control m-b">1</span>
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span id="resultado3"
            type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b">2</span>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span id="resulta2"
            type="number" name="total" class="form-control m-b">3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        var clase=$(this).attr('class');
        // alert(clase)
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // alert(id)
        var texto=$(this).text();
        // alert(texto)
        var name=$(this).attr('name');
        // $(this).remove();
        $(this).after('<input id="'+id+'" class="'+clase+'" type="text" name="'+name+'" value="'+texto+'">');
        $(this).remove(); 
        //si descomentas esto borra el span y pone el input en su lugar si el input lo cambias a type="text"
    });
```

$('form').submit();
        // alert("hola")
      })

Este código tal cual lo que hace es cambiar los span que tienes por inputs tipo texto y pone el texto del span como valor, de forma que, si tienes un form puedas enviarlo. Como me faltan los datos del formulario que envía y las variables de php, su contenido al menos, no puedo matizar mas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91629/discussion-on-answer-by-emerita-como-hacer-que-un-span-me-lo-tome-como-input).

Comment: Mis disculpas, pero no se abrir salas de chat y estaba en el metro, asi que con el movil tampoco podia hacer gran cosa. Gracias por moverlo @Alvaro

Comment: no hay que disculparse, es un mensaje automático que sale cuando los moderadores mueven los comentarios al chat. Gracias por colaborar en el sitio :)

Answer (score 0):

Tan simple como poner un atributo que se llama contenteditable

[Aquí la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/contenteditable)

```html
<span contenteditable>Ja! easy</span>
```